# Removing duplicate elements in an ArrayList and adding the total number of occurrences in parentheses after the first element

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Beginner here. I have a String ArrayList that essentially looks like this (but with changing values dependent on user input) when printed:

[22, 37, 77, 77, 98, 101, 104, 107, 107, 107, 150]

I want to remove the duplicate elements and add the total number of occurrences in parentheses after the first element, so it will look like this:

[22, 37, 77 (2), 98, 101, 104, 107 (3), 150]

I've figured out how to remove the duplicate elements, but I can't quite figure out the rest.

Here's my code so far (the ArrayList is called duplicates):

```
int q, z;
for(q = 0; q < duplicates.size() - 1; q++) {  
    for(z = q + 1; z < duplicates.size() - 1; z++) {
        if(duplicates.get(q).equals(duplicates.get(z))) {
            duplicates.remove(q);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(duplicates);
```

The resulting output is:

[22, 37, 77, 98, 101, 104, 107, 150]

Does anybody have any suggestion for how I can get those parentheses with the number of occurrences in there? I've been struggling to come up with a way to count the duplicates removed for each value, but all I've been able to count is the total number of duplicates removed period, which isn't particularly useful.

The ArrayList was originally an Integer ArrayList, but I changed it to a String ArrayList so I could add non-number characters to the elements.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a ***[Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)***. You can use this to associate keys with *useful* values. In this case the key would be the elements of your array to be processed, and the value would be the number of occurrences of each element in the array. Your pseudocode would be:

```
initialize a map of appropriate size and type
iterate the array to be processed. for each element in array:

set key:= current element in array
set value := value from map corresponding to key
if value is null, initialize value to 1
store value for key in map
```

Then at the end you will iterate the keys of the map and print out both the key and its corresponding value.

- [Initializing a HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int%29)
- [Retrieving values from a
  Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [Storing values in a Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,V%29)

Answer (score 1):

> The ArrayList was originally an Integer ArrayList, but I changed it to a String ArrayList so I could add non-number characters to the elements.

This is a mistake.  Don't mix up how you want to store your data in your code and how you want to display it to the user.  If you store your values as a `List` of `String` you're making things harder for yourself.  Store the values in the form that's easiest to code and only covert to strings once you want to display them.

So what you want is a list of unique numbers and count for each of the these.  A `Map` would be ideal as it maps a key - in your cause the integer - to a value - the count.

So you need to loop over your numbers and then count them in the `Map`.  In the code below I'm assuming `list` is a `List<Integer>`.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for (int number : list) {
  int count = counts.containsKey(number) ? counts.get(number) : 0;
  count += 1;
  counts.put(number,count);
}
```

You can then build up your output by looping over `Map.keySet()` or `Map.entrySet()`,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you keep the list as a list of integers. Don't use `System.out.println(duplicates)`, but do a loop yourself. It's really easy anyway.

**Counting the occurrences:**

I suggest you maintain a `Map<Integer, Integer>` which maps numbers to the number of occurrences. This can be initialized in a first pass like this:

1. For each element *i* in the list       (`for (int i : duplicates)`)

   1. If *i* is not in the map       (`map.containsKey(i)`)

      1. add the mapping *i* -> 0         (`map.put(i, 0)`)
   2. Increment the value for key *i*      (`map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1)`)

**Printing the list with the number of occurrences:**

You the print the list as follows:

1. Create a `HashSet<Integer> printed` for already printed numbers
2. For each element *i* in the list

   1. If *i* is `printed`, do, continue:  (`if (printed.contains(i)) continue;`)
   2. Print *i*
   3. If the mapping has a value > 1 for *i*, print the number in parenthesis
   4. Add *i* to printed.  (`printed.add(i)`)

---

Once you're done practicing loops you can remove dups by just doing

```
list = new ArrayList<Integer>(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

declare an `ArrayList<Integer>` for counting:

```
ArrayList<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and then when you remove a duplicate, bump the count

```
            duplicates.remove(q);
            counts.set(q, counts.get(q) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashMap is Good enough for you . Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. So , I recommend using a LinkedHashMap as follow:

```
    public static LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> removeDuplicate(List<String> list)
{
    LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(String str:list)
    {
        Integer count = map.get(str);
        if(count == null)
        {
            map.put(str, 1);
        }else{
            map.put(str, ++count);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("123");
    list.add("45");
    list.add("678");
    list.add("123");
    System.out.println(removeDuplicate(list));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With little help of (IMHO very useful) Google's Library [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can write this:

```
List<String> duplicate = ImmutableList.of("22", "37", "77", "77", "98", "101", "104", "107", "107", "107", "150");

System.out.println(duplicate); 

Multiset<String> withoutDuplicate = LinkedHashMultiset.create();
withoutDuplicate.addAll(duplicate);

System.out.println(withoutDuplicate);
```

This would produce

```
[22, 37, 77, 77, 98, 101, 104, 107, 107, 107, 150]
[22, 37, 77 x 2, 98, 101, 104, 107 x 3, 150]
```

It's not exactly your format, but for that it's a two-liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> completeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
completeList.add(22);
completeList.add(22);
completeList.add(37);
completeList.add(77);
completeList.add(77);
completeList.add(98);
completeList.add(101);
completeList.add(107);
completeList.add(107);
completeList.add(107);
completeList.add(150);

System.out.println(completeList);

// Using a sortedSet to remove the duplicates
SortedSet<Integer> nonDupSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(completeList);
System.out.println(nonDupSet);

List<String> datawithParan = new ArrayList<String>();
//Looping through the completeList with the nonDup List and counting the dups.
// and then populating a List with the required Format
for (Integer nonDup: nonDupSet) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer complete: completeList) {                      
      if(nonDup == complete) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    datawithParan.add(nonDup +"(" + count + ")");
}
System.out.println(datawithParan);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full code for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Make list */
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    input.add("12");
    input.add("11");
    input.add("11");
    input.add("12");
    input.add("12");
    input.add("15");
    input.add("12");
    input.add("17");
    input.add("18");
    input.add("11");

    /*
     * count duplicates
     */
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String str : input) {
        if (map.containsKey(str)) {
            Integer prevCount = map.get(str);
            map.put(str, ++prevCount);
        } else {
            map.put(str, 0);
        }
    }

    /*
     * make string to display
     */
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer count = entry.getValue();
        if (count == 0) {
            sb.append(key + ", ");
        } else
            sb.append(key + "(" + count + "), ");
    }
    String tmp = sb.toString();
    String output = tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - 2); //remove last ", "
    System.out.println("[" + output + "]");

}
```

Comment: A) You did the guys homework (not very helpful) B) You're messing up the order in the list. (not even a correct solution) C) Seems to break horribly on the empty list.

Comment: A) thanks for the suggestion.   B)I corrected the code - used LinkedHashMap.  C) Isn't it great to let jta1991 check all the cases to make his homework perfect?